# Override run() method in ActionListener

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, actionlistener, jcheckbox

I want to get access to `t.isStopped()` in the overridden `run()` method
but I get the following Error.

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable t inside an inner class defined in a different method

If I set t to a final variable

> The local variable t may not have been initialized

```
<!-- language: java -->

jHibernateCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Sleep / Hibernate after ");
jHibernateTextField = new JTextField("240");

jHibernateCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


     StoppableThread t = new StoppableThread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           t.setIsRunning(true);
           long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
           int minutes = Integer.parseInt(jHibernateTextField.getText());
           long secounds = minutes * 60;
           long millisecounds = secounds * 1000;
           long elapsedTime = new Date().getTime();

           do {
              try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 millisecounds -= new Date().getTime() - elapsedTime;
                 secounds = millisecounds / 1000;
                 if(secounds < 60) {
                    jHibernateTextField.setText("" + secounds);
                    jRemainingLabel.setText(" secounds remaining");
                 }
                 else {
                    jHibernateTextField.setText("" + secounds / 60);
                    jRemainingLabel.setText(" minutes remaining");
                 }
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
              elapsedTime = new Date().getTime();
           }while(!t.isStopped() && timestamp + minutes * 60 * 1000 > new Date().getTime());

           jHibernateTextField.setText("" + minutes);

           if(t.isStopped()) return;
           else {
              console.out("Computer wird schlafen gelegt =)");
              //Hibernate (siehe LAPTOP)
           }

        }
     };

     Thread thread = new Thread(t);


     if(jHibernateCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        jHibernateTextField.setEnabled(false);
        thread.start();
     }
     else {
        jHibernateTextField.setEnabled(true);
        t.setIsStopped(true);
     }
  }
```

});

Is it possible to get access to the variable t in an inner class
or does anyone know a way how to stop the thread if the checkbox was clicked again?

I just want the timer stops working when I click again on the jHibernateCheckBox... maybe there is another way?

Comment: What is the line or lines of code that is displaying the error?

Comment: On which line are you getting this error? if its t.setIsRunning(true), try replacing t with this.

Comment: at every line in the run method where t is present... if I replace the t with this it have no effect on the code

Answer (score 2):

Not related to your question, but in the code snippet you posted you violate the Swing threading rules. All Swing components should only be accessed/modified from the Event Dispatch Thread. Modifying Swing components from your `StoppableThread` is not allowed and might result in weird behavior at runtime.

After a quick glance on your code, it seems you could use a `SwingWorker` and fire progress events. More or less the same mechanism as illustrated in the [`JProgressBar` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) (the part where they use a `SwingWorker`)

Consult the [Swing concurreny tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using 'this' keyword inside the implementation?

Comment: I tried it before I have asked this question, I tried everything I know =)

Answer (score 1):

```
                  StoppableThread t = new StoppableThread() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        t.setIsRunning(true);
                        long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(jHibernateTextField.getText());
                        long secounds = minutes * 60;
                        long millisecounds = secounds * 1000;
                        long elapsedTime = new Date().getTime();

                        do {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                millisecounds -= new Date().getTime() - elapsedTime;
                                secounds = millisecounds / 1000;
                                if(secounds < 60) {
                                    jHibernateTextField.setText("" + secounds);
                                    jRemainingLabel.setText(" secounds remaining");
                                }
                                else {
                                    jHibernateTextField.setText("" + secounds / 60);
                                    jRemainingLabel.setText(" minutes remaining");
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            elapsedTime = new Date().getTime();
                        }while(!t.isStopped() && timestamp + minutes * 60 * 1000 > new Date().getTime());

                        jHibernateTextField.setText("" + minutes);

                        if(t.isStopped()) return;
                        else {
                            console.out("Computer wird schlafen gelegt =)");
                            //Hibernate (siehe LAPTOP)
                        }

                    }
                };
```

Inside the run method replace t with `this`.

Comment: if I press on the jHibernateCheckBox and the thread is active the attribute t.setIsStopped(true) sets to true, but in the run method the t.isStopped() or this.isStopped() output already false...

Answer (score -1):

I've tried something new, and now it works. I don't know if this is a blundering but 
just take a look.

```java
private StoppableThread t;

public void initComponents() {
...
...
t = new StoppableThread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setIsRunning(true);
            long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(jHibernateTextField.getText());
            long secounds = minutes * 60;
            long millisecounds = secounds * 1000;
            long elapsedTime = new Date().getTime();

            do {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    millisecounds -= new Date().getTime() - elapsedTime;
                    secounds = millisecounds / 1000;
                    if(secounds < 60) {
                        jHibernateTextField.setText("" + secounds);
                        jRemainingLabel.setText(" secounds remaining");
                    }
                    else {
                        jHibernateTextField.setText("" + secounds / 60);
                        jRemainingLabel.setText(" minutes remaining");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                elapsedTime = new Date().getTime();
            }while(!isStopped() && timestamp + minutes * 60 * 1000 > new Date().getTime());

            jHibernateTextField.setText("" + minutes);

            if(isStopped()) return;
            else {
                console.out("Computer wird schlafen gelegt =)");
                //Hibernate (siehe LAPTOP)
            }

        }
    };

    jHibernateCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            Thread thread = new Thread(AutoBarbarPanel.this.t);


            if(jHibernateCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                jHibernateTextField.setEnabled(false);
                thread.start();
            }
            else {
                jHibernateTextField.setEnabled(true);
                t.setIsStopped(true);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Thanks for all answers

Comment: please tell me the solution without violating the EDT rules ;)

Comment: read the tutorial referenced by @Robin and apply it to your code ;-)